# How to get Image with text on top/infront? (Google Classroom Home Image Format)

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make an Image with Text on top, just like Google CLassroom. But first I want to test Image and then Text. Instead, I got the image overlapping the text. [Image Overlapping text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jje3j.jpg)
Then I move the Image code after the text. How to get simple G classroom format
[Text then Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJasi.jpg)

```
@Composable
fun ClassImage(
//    icon: VectorAsset,
//    label: String,
//    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val imageAlpha = 1f
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 8.dp, top = 8.dp, end = 8.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        color = colors.primary.copy(alpha = 0.12f)
    ) {
        TextButton(
            onClick = {},
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) 
                {
                    Image(
                        imageResource(id = R.drawable.class1),
                        alpha = imageAlpha
                    )
                    Column {
                        Text("Alfred Sisley", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                        ProvideEmphasis(emphasis = EmphasisAmbient.current.medium) {
                            Text("3 minutes ago", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To put Text on top of the Image you can use Box, which is similar to old FrameLayout.

I'm not sure want you wanted to achieve, but if smth like this:
[image]

Then you can do it this way:

```
Surface(
   shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
   modifier = Modifier
      .preferredHeight(128.dp)
      .clickable(onClick = {})
) {
  Box {
    Image(
       vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
       alpha = imageAlpha,
       contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
      Text(
         "Alfred Sisley",
         fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
         style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
      ProvideEmphasis(emphasis = EmphasisAmbient.current.medium) {
        Text("3 minutes ago", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2)
      }
      Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
      Text(text = "Footer", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant Card and not Box

Answer (score 0):

With `1.0.0-beta02` you can use a `Box` as parent container.
Something like:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max))
    {
        Image(
            painterResource(id = R.drawable.xx),
            "contentDescription",
            alpha = 0.8f,
            modifier = Modifier.requiredHeight(100.dp)
        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom) {
            Text("Alfred Sisley",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
                Text("3 minutes ago", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2)
            }
        } 
    }
```

[image]